# Is there a way to config couchdb such that it automatically adds a timestamp to a new revision on the _utils view?

Tags: couchdb

We expose couchdb to our users to update the document as they want, the problem is that currently, the versions don't have a timestamp

Is there a way to config couchdb to have timestamp added when a document is revised?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with an [update function](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html?highlight=timestamp#update-functions).  You'll need to create a [design document](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/common.html) for your database, and define an appropriate update function, which updates the timestamp.